# Regex to escape quotes and return parameters

Tags: .net, regex, email

I have a regular expression `@(?<parameter>[\w_]+)` which is used to `@` at the beginning and will consider it as parameter and will split the string for further processing. Everything was good till I had email address as a parameter.

Whenever I try to work with email address, *regex* will split it at `@`. I am looking for thoughts to extend this *regex* so that it passes below validation:

Test:

```
hello  @1,@2,"ax@test"
```

Return:

```
parameter: 1
parameter: 2
parameter: ax@test
```

instead of:

```
parameter: 1
parameter: 2
parameter: test
```

Comment: .net. I changed the regex to exclude "?" and include new group but that is not helping either.

Comment: what is your expected output `test` or `ax@test`? Please confirm.

Comment: ax@test is what i want..

Comment: If `"abc"` is there then it is included in expected output

Comment: Have a look at my updated post

Comment: This will not work if i have an alpanumeric value like @he1. It should return he1 but will not.Can i include parameter(some static text)  in output apart from results. Ex: instead of saying 1 it should say parameter 1..

Comment: Sure let me change the pattern.

Comment: change `\d+` to `\w+` for e.g `(?<=@)(\w+)|"(.*(?=@)[^"]*)"` Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV8qU8/10)

Comment: This will not work. For eaxample if string is hello  @1,@25,"ax@test","@demo",@1he1 it will return ax@test,@demo as one parameter.

Comment: It's greedy pattern that's why its capturing next value as one group. Try with reluctant quantifier as updated it in my post.

Comment: Can i add "parameter" to result?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. What you want please explain with some samples. What is expected output.

Comment: instead of returning the match as 1,2,test i would like it to return target 1, target 2, target test, target ax@test...and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: yes i edited it in my post. Sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: Is there anyway we can do this without using substitution.

Comment: Any thoughts? Do you think i should be able to get this working using just regex without substitution?

Comment: have you tried my updated post?

Comment: i don't want to use substitution and would like regex to return matches in parameter 1, parameter test, parameter ax@test format.

Comment: Have you read my post again carefully? I don't have any knowledge about C#, I just know a little about regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Get the matched group from index 1

```
[@"]((?<=@)\w+|\w*@[^"]*)"?
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV8qU8/19)

Replace it with `parameter: $1` as shown in the demo.

String literals for use in programs C#:

```
@"[@""]((?<=@)\w+|\w*@[^""]*)""?"
```

---

Input:

```
@1,@25,"ax@test","@demo",@1he1
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-2]   `1`
MATCH 2
1.  [4-6]   `25`
MATCH 3
1.  [8-15]  `ax@test`
MATCH 4
1.  [18-23] `@demo`
MATCH 5
1.  [26-30] `1he1`
```

Comment: FYI `\w` includes the underscore character, so `[\w_]` is the same as just `\w`. Further, the `\b` is unnecessary, as `\w+` will consume everything up to the next word boundary.

Comment: @Bohemian thanks I missed that part. Updated the post. I confused with `-` hyphen.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand about `\b`. Please can you explain me with an example. I am learner.

Comment: The `+` quantifier is "greedy", meaning it consumes as much as possible (while still allowing the entire expression to match). `\b` matches the boundary between a word and non-word character, so `\w+` and `\w+\b` are therefore equivalent; `\w+` will consume `\b` all contiguous word characters, stopping at the end of the word, which is the definition of `\b`

Comment: This will not work as the third match will still return "test" instead of "ax@test".